# client side validation fails when partial control is loaded using Ajax.ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

I've got a partial control with `Ajax.BeginForm` containing simple form with one textbox and validation message. Model is using data annotations to set this field to required.

When above partial control gets loaded in the view directly using `Html.RenderPartial` then client side validation works fine.

When above partial control gets loaded using `Ajax.ActionLink` then client validation stops working ( form gets submitted with empty textbox and server side validation works fine ):

```
Ajax.ActionLink("Create New Job Note", "CreateNew", "JobNotes", 
                new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "CreateNewJobNote",
                                  HttpMethod="GET" })
```

I've got references to following javascript on my masterpage :

```
<script src="/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcValidation.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Why does client side validation not work when I load the partial control using `Ajax.ActionLink`?

========== EDIT ==============

As requested, here are relevant code quotes :

1)
I'm loading my partial control containing textbox with this code :

```
<%:Ajax.ActionLink("Create New Job Note", "CreateNew", "JobNotes", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "CreateNewJobNote", HttpMethod="GET" })%>
```

Controller method :

```
public ActionResult CreateNew()
        {
            return PartialView("JobNotesCreateNew", new NewJobNoteModel());           
        }
```

2)
JobNotesCreateNew.ascx :

```
<% Html.EnableClientValidation();%>
<% using (Ajax.BeginForm("CreateNew", "JobNotes", FormMethod.Post, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "JobNotes" }, new { id = "CreateNewJobNoteForm" }))
   { %>
    <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Please correct errors on the form.")%>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Fields</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Note)%>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Note)%>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Note)%>
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
            <%: Ajax.ActionLink("Cancel", "Cancel", "JobNotes", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "CreateNewJobNote", HttpMethod = "GET" })%>
        </p>

    </fieldset>

<% } %>
```

That's it.
So, to sum up:

1. a view with ajax action link to my partial control gets loaded.
2. User clicks on "Create New Job Note"
   ajax action link which loads my
   partial control correctly.
3. When form from
   JobNotesCreateNew.ascx gets
   submitted using "Create" submit
   button I expect client side
   validation to check if TextBoxFor
   for model.Note is not empty.

But client side validation doesn't happen and form is posted to the server. 
I can see this in firebug. 
I can also debug following controller method on server side in VS 2010 :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateNew(NewJobNoteModel newJobNote)
```

So my question is : why client side validation is broken?

Thanks.

========== EDIT : 17/11/2010 ==============

Interesting.
I'm using data annotations validation on the model :

```
public class NewJobNoteModel
    {
        [Required]
        public string Note { get; set; }
    }
```

Since above validation works fine on client side when using Html.BeginForm() I was assuming it should work in Ajax.BeginForm() scenario as well.
Am I mistaken here? Should I really trigger the validation myself on client side?
I will investigate the article, had a quick look and CompleteFunction looks quite manual over there, I was hoping things to be more automated there.

Thanks!

========== EDIT : 25/11/2010 ==============

OK I found a solution to my problem here :
http://adammcraventech.wordpress.com/2010/06/11/asp-net-mvc2-ajax-executing-dynamically-loaded-javascript/

The AjaxLoadedContentScriptFix.js javascript seems to be working fine for me.

This is the kind of answer I was looking for.
All the other tips like using custom client side validation in AjaxOptions of Ajax.BeginForm - c'mon people :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as mentioned in the original post, here is the solution : 
http://adammcraventech.wordpress.com/2010/06/11/asp-net-mvc2-ajax-executing-dynamically-loaded-javascript/

Answer (score 1):

@Maciek I need to see more of your code to make a correct diagnosis. 
However, there are a few things that come to mind.

- First, you can use one of the
  AjaxOptions in your function to call
  Javascript OnSuccess or OnBegin - you use it like this  new AjaxOptions {
  OnBegin = "YourJavascriptFunction"
  }. Specifically, your process would look something like this.

> Ajax.ActionLink("Create New Job Note", "CreateNew", "JobNotes", 
>                   new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "CreateNewJobNote",
>    OnBegin = "YourJavascriptFunction", 
>                                     HttpMethod="Post" })

- Second, I noticed that you are not using a post action. Is there a reason why?
  Usually you want to execute a Post and not a Get when you are sending a form back.
  If I were you, I would change that. I changed it in the code segment I posted above.
- Third, you should make sure that your
  JavaScript function isn't calling
  controls that don't exist yet.

These are, of course, some basic things to check. However, if you need more help, you should post your entire page so that I can see the code and see your JavaScript functions and how you have your page arranged.

Good luck to you!

//**************************************************************//
**UPDATED 11/16/2010**
//*************************************************************************************//

Hi Maciek,

I looked at the new code you posted in your question and I noticed a few things.
First, I don't see your code for checking the text box. If you want the system to check your text box before your Ajax postback, you need to put in code to make the system do it. You need a JavaScript function that is called using an AjaxOption parameter as I specified in my first answer. That validation does not happen automatically.

Take a look at this article so that you can learn how to do what you are trying to do.

[link text](http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2010/07/18/asp-net-mvc-client-side-validation-with-ajax-beginform.aspx)

Once you put in the correct code to perform validation you will be able to check your data on the client side. As a side note, I would like to add that you should MAKE SURE that your process validates on the server too. A user could turn off JavaScript and if your code doesn't perform the appropriate checks on the server, you will end up with problems.

Comment: Thanks for answering, let me edit my question to add relevant code samples.